# android intent filter pattern matching

Tags: android, android-intent

My Intent filter looks like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="*" 
                  android:host="*" 
                  android:pathPattern="/pickup.jsp\?h=.+&p=.*&l=-?[0-9]+" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I get parser error in eclipse:

```
[com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] 
Parser exception for C:\projects\myapp\AndroidManifest.xml: 
The reference to entity "p" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

I'm trying to match the URL `/path/pickup.jsp?h=handle&p=&l=4234` for any scheme and any host using a regular expression.  Is that possible?  If so, how would I match it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to match the URL /path/pickup.jsp?h=handle&p=&l=4234

That is not possible. Query parameters are not part of the `Uri` from an `<intent-filter>` standpoint and therefore cannot be matched upon.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the '&' symbol is being interpreted by the XML parser.

You should replace `&` with `&amp;`

Comment: I replaced it, now the parse error is gone, but the intent filter doesn't match the URL.

Comment: no it probably wouldn't .. sorry not much help.  Not sure about the downvote either ... I solved the error ... oh well ;)